# Problema com função mouseleave do jQuery para disparar popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Eu estou usando a função `mouseleave` para abrir uma popup quando o usuário mover o mouse para fora do site.

Esse é o código:

```
jQuery('body').mouseleave(function() {
            if (!jQuery('body').hasClass('leave-on') && localStorage.getItem("leave") != "closed") {
                jQuery('body').addClass('leave-on');
            }
        });
```

Mas eu tenho um problema com a trigger porque se eu clico no botão com a setinha para deslizar o slider, o `mouseleave` é disparado e a popup aparece.

Os botões que estão fazendo o `mouseleave` ativar:

[image: os botões que estão fazendo o <code>mouseleave</code> ativar]

Comment: Esse site está em português, então da próxima vez, por favor poste em português. Já traduzi a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente ao clicar em um elemento o evento `mouseleave` é disparado. Seria isso um *bug* uma vez que o mouse não saiu do body? Ou o evento `click` esteja disparando o evento? Fiz uma breve pesquisa e vi comentários de que isso seria mesmo um *bug*, enfim...

Para resolver isso fiz este código que cancela o evento `mouseleave` ao clique e restaurando-o após um breve *delay* de dez milésimos de segundo (10ms). *Esse delay é necessário porque se você restaurar o evento imediatamente ele será disparado de qualquer jeito.*

Mas mudei o foco dos eventos ao `document` em vez do `body`, o que é mais interessante porque irá detectar o mouse saindo da área do documento em vez do `body`, o que não é a mesma coisa. O `body` da página é apenas onde a tag `<body>` possui conteúdo, já o `document` é a área toda da janela onde é exibida a página, independentemente se tem conteúdo ou não.

> Comentei as linhas do `if` para não exibir erro no snippet por causa
>   do localStorage. Ao copiar o código, descomente as linhas.

**Veja:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var t = jQuery(this);
   t.on("click", function(){
      t.off("mouseleave");
      setTimeout(function(){
         t.on("mouseleave", function(){
            console.log("saiu"); // apenas para ilustrar, pode remover esta linha
            //if (!jQuery('body').hasClass('leave-on') && localStorage.getItem("leave") != "closed") {
               // jQuery('body').addClass('leave-on');
            //}
         });
      }, 10);
   });
   // disparo o evento para ativar o mouseleave
   t.trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Ao clicar na div abaixo o evento mouseleave não é disparado e o console.log não será exibido:
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red;">Clique aqui</div>
```

Comment: eu estava lendo aqui e é algum problema em relação ao svg...
esqueci de falar q `pointer-events:none` resolve o problema porém o botão não ficará mais funcional pois não aceitará o evento de click.

dê uma olhada nesse tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631598/both-mouseleave-and-mouseout-triggering-too-often
e
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636602/mouseout-mouseleave-gets-fired-when-mouse-moves-inside-the-svg-path-element

Comment: Qual é o código mesmo desse svg?

Comment: Testei nos outros svg da pagina e eles também ativam o popup ao colocar o mouse em cima... Exemplo de um svg que no caso é só um icone com um link:
`<svg class="icon-blog">
                        <use xlink:href="#blog"></use>
                    </svg>` 
Obs: apenas no mozilla que ocorre o problema de ativar o popup ao colocar o mouse em um svg como esse.

Comment: Abre a popup apenas ao passar o mouse em cima, sem clicar?

Comment: exato... apenas no mozilla q ta ocorrendo isso